# XSLT 1.0 delete nodes

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

How can i delete some specific nodes?

In my example, i have lot of nodes at segment REF, but i just want to use REF with Qualifier GS, all others should be deleted.

```
<ITEM>
    <ITEM_NUMBER_EN>123456789</ITEM_NUMBER_EN>
    <ITEM_NUMBER_IN>1234</ITEM_NUMBER_IN>
    <ITEM_NUMBER_SA>1234</ITEM_NUMBER_SA>
    <QUANTITY>1</QUANTITY>
    <QUANTITY_UNIT>PCE</QUANTITY_UNIT>
    <LINE_ITEM_NUMBER>1</LINE_ITEM_NUMBER>
    <AMOUNT_DETAILS>
        <QUALIFIER>AAA</QUALIFIER>
        <AMOUNT>1.00</AMOUNT>
        <CURRENCY>EUR</CURRENCY>
    </AMOUNT_DETAILS>
    <REF>
        <QUALIFIER>CR</QUALIFIER>
        <REFERENCE>1234</REFERENCE>
        <ADDITIONAL_INFO/>
    </REF>
    <REF>
        <QUALIFIER>GS</QUALIFIER>
        <REFERENCE>5647</REFERENCE>
        <ADDITIONAL_INFO/>
    </REF>
    <REF>
        <QUALIFIER>LI</QUALIFIER>
        <REFERENCE>1</REFERENCE>
        <ADDITIONAL_INFO/>
    </REF>
    <PACKAGE_DETAILS>
        <!-- ... -->
    </PACKAGE_DETAILS>
</ITEM>
```

Do you need more info about my XML?

Edit: Output should be:

```
<ITEM>
    <ITEM_NUMBER_EN>123456789</ITEM_NUMBER_EN>
    <ITEM_NUMBER_IN>1234</ITEM_NUMBER_IN>
    <ITEM_NUMBER_SA>1234</ITEM_NUMBER_SA>
    <QUANTITY>1</QUANTITY>
    <QUANTITY_UNIT>PCE</QUANTITY_UNIT>
    <LINE_ITEM_NUMBER>1</LINE_ITEM_NUMBER>
    <AMOUNT_DETAILS>
        <QUALIFIER>AAA</QUALIFIER>
        <AMOUNT>1.00</AMOUNT>
        <CURRENCY>EUR</CURRENCY>
    </AMOUNT_DETAILS>
    <REF>
        <QUALIFIER>GS</QUALIFIER>
        <REFERENCE>5647</REFERENCE>
        <ADDITIONAL_INFO/>
    </REF>
    <PACKAGE_DETAILS>
        <!-- ... -->
    </PACKAGE_DETAILS>
</ITEM>
```

My current attempt is like this:

```
<!--delete REF node-->
<xsl:template match="REF">
  <xsl:for-each select ="./REF">
    <xsl:if test="./QUALIFIER='LI'">
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
  <!--copy all other nodes-->
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
</xsl:template>
```

My only solution at the moment is, to delete all others separately with:

```
<xsl:template match="REF[QUALIFIER='CR']"/>

<xsl:template match="REF[QUALIFIER='LI']"/>
```

Comment: Can you show us your XSLT? What you have tried so far?

Comment: <!--delete REF node-->
  <xsl:template match="REF">    
      <xsl:for-each  select ="./REF">
  <xsl:if test="./QUALIFIER='LI'">             
        </xsl:if> 
      </xsl:for-each>
     <!--copy all other nodes-->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:template>

Comment: <xsl:template match="REF[@QUALIFER='LI']"/>

Comment: thx!! i used: <xsl:template match="REF[QUALIFIER !='GS']"/>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to delete all `<REF>` nodes where the qualifier is not "GS".

```
<xsl:template match="REF[@QUALIFER != 'GS']" />
```

That's all that is necessary, in addition to the identity template (which you already seem to have).